# Saved video filtering on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image

How can I make the process that filtering saved video in photo library in iOS?

I got URLs of videos in the library using AssetsLibrary framework,

then, made a preview for the video.

Next step, I wanna make filtering process for video using CIFilter.

In case of real time issue, I made video filter process using AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.

But in case of saved video, I don't know how to make filter process.

Do I use AVAsset? If I must use that, how can I filter it? and how to save it?

always thank you.

Comment: Idk, but I'm working on this now too... Will let you know what I find if I figure it out!

Comment: Thank you mate. Check this framework!! http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been using as well... had to add a couple of things, but that is the beauty of github^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
 AVAsset *theAVAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:mNormalVideoURL options:nil];
       NSError *error = nil;
        float width = theAVAsset.naturalSize.width;
        float height = theAVAsset.naturalSize.height; 
        AVAssetReader *mAssetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:theAVAsset error:&error]; 
        [theAVAsset release];




    NSArray *videoTracks = [theAVAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]; 
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];
    mPrefferdTransform = [videoTrack preferredTransform];


    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
   AVAssetReaderTrackOutput* mAssetReaderOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:options];

    [mAssetReader addOutput:mAssetReaderOutput];
    [mAssetReaderOutput release];


    CMSampleBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    //CMSampleBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    while ( [mAssetReader status]==AVAssetReaderStatusReading ){
            buffer = [mAssetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];//read next image.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at CVImageBufferRef pixBuf = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sbuf) then you can have the image pointer first address, so you can add filter to pixBuf, but i find that the performance is not good, If you have any new idea,we can discuss about it further.

Comment: I found GPUImage framework and it works beautifully. Visit this link http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework